# Python and JSON and Discord.py - TypeError list indices must be integers not str

Tags: json

```
       description = "**Next: **{streamer_next}\n**Later:**".format(
            streamer_next=(
                data["data"]["username"]
            ),
        )
```

JSON:
{"data":[{"time":23,"habbo":"Position","username":"ashley"},{"time":0,"habbo":"Star-Catcher","username":"Steph"},{"time":11,"habbo":"qotreboop","username":"Rob"},{"time":16,"habbo":"devy123","username":"Devy"}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with `data["data"][0]["username"] + data["data"][1]["username"]` etc